# ORACLE-06512 error while running utlpwdmg.sql

Tags: oracle11g, passwords

I am trying to increase the complexity of password rules for the databases I manage. As a result, I made few additions to the utlpwdmg.sql file.

This file does not result in compilation errors but while running it, I get the following error messages.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

ORA-06512: at "ISU_DBA_SCHED.VERIFY_FUNCTION_11G", line 49

ORA-06512: at line 11
```

[At Line 49](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UhuG.png)

```
    -- Check if the password is same as the username reversed
    FOR i in REVERSE 1..length(username) LOOP
    reverse_user := reverse_user || substr(username, i, 1);
    END LOOP;

    IF NLS_LOWER(password) = NLS_LOWER(reverse_user) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20004, 'Password same as username reversed');

    END IF;
```

[At Line 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWVsa.png)

```
    -- ispunct boolean;
```

Note:

1. I use SQL Developer to run utlpwdmg.sql
2. I checked the entire program for data type mismatches and data length issues but found nothing that could cause ORACLE-06502
3. It is unclear while my code results in ORA-06512

Comment: I see no issue in your loop nor at line 11 seeing as how it's a comment there's no chance it creating an error.  I suspect that there is a missing ";" somewhere ... have you checked for that?

Comment: Is there a way I can trace the exact point of failure ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sql Developer, I use Toad.  Is there a way you can step through your code with Sql Developer, a debugger?  If so, set breakpoints before each point where the error is generated and step through the code.

Comment: This link, http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/plsql_debug/plsql_debug_otn.htm, contains information on how to debug with Sql Developer.